# Abelian group of order pq, two different prime numbers

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, prime-numbers, abelian-groups

> $G$ is an abelian group of order $pq$, two different prime numbers. Need to prove that there is an element of order $p$ and of order $q$.

The proof that I found goes like this:

By Lagrange, order of an element in finite group divides the order of the group. So it can be, then it is id. So let take an element which is not the id. So it's order can be $p$,$q$ or $pq$. If it is $pq$, then it is easy to show an element from each order $p$ and $q$. Ok, so let's take and element of an order that isn't pq. Then it is $p$ or $q$. Let it be $q$. Now we will show that there is an element from order $p$.

Then let us assume that there isn't such element. So for each other element it's order is $q$ (because if it pq it's fine and id there is only one). 
$q$ is prime, then the cyclic sub-group that he creates is from order $q$, but the id is already counted, so each such element generates $q-1$ elements. 
$$$$
But that can't be because $q-1$ doesn't divides $q(p-1)$.

> Can somebody explain to me if there is any reason that $q-1$ doesn't divide $p-1$ for two different prime numbers?

And secondly,

> Is there any more algebraic way to prove this ?

Comment: But $q-1$ can divide $p-1$, many examples, like $q=3$ and $p=5$.

Comment: Yes, I saw this examples in my mind eather. So this is incomplete and incorrect proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you saw in the comments, your conjecture is false. Here is a way you can prove your result, just off the top of my head, without even assuming $G$ is abelian. There probably exists a cleaner proof somewhere.

Say you have an element $a$ of order $q$, generating a subgroup $C_q\subset G$. Now by Lagrange's theorem $C_q$ is the unique subgroup of order $q$ in $G$, hence it is normal. To see this, note that for any $g\in G$, the conjugate subgroup $gC_qg^{-1}$ also has order $q$, hence $gC_q g^{-1}=C_q$ for all $g\in G$. It follows that the quotient group $G/C_q$ is cyclic of order $p$. Choose a generator $b$ of $G/C_p$ and consider once of its preimages $b'$ in $G$. Note that $b'$ is not in $C_q$. Then the image of $b'^p$ will be in $C_q$, hence $b'$ has order either $p$ or $pq$. If it is the latter, $b'^q$ has order $p$.

Comment: So if it isn't abelian (but in our case it is easier, because it is), Largrange theorem say's the for each $d||G|$ there is unique sub-group of it's order? Ran out of my mind. I do remember a theorem that say's that if G is abelian, then it has one unique cyclic sub-group of each order which devides $|G|$, but I guess that is eather from Lagrange's Theorem and from the fact that any sub-group of abelian group is cyclic (am I remember right?). Yes, that a good one, I used it in another exercize, but then I noticed that I didn't said a word about it's normality, and your notion was just in time.

Comment: No, Lagrange's theorem says that if $G$ is a group of order $g$, $H$ is a subgroup of order $h$, then $h$ divides $g$ and $G$ has exactly $g/h$ left (or right) cosets of $H$. My proof above assumed that you had identified an element of order $q$ in your group, which generates a subgroup of the same order. By the assumption that $|G|=pq$, where $q$ and $p$ are different primes, this makes this the unique subgroup of that order, and then you can show that it is normal.

Comment: @Ilya.K. Also, not every subgroup of an abelian group is cyclic. However, any group of prime order is cyclic.

Comment: Espen, can you just explain why $p$ and $q$ **coprime**, it makes the sub-group unique ? Why shouldn't be another group of same order ? 
Because that's what I assumed in the first incorrect proof.

Comment: @Ilya.K In this case, assume that we had two distinct such subgroups, $H_1$ and $H_2$. Then their intersection is trivial (do you see why?) so $q^2$ divides the order of $G$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Yes, about the intersection. because they are both cyclic and if there was another element wich is not id in the intersection, they were the same group.
and $q^{2}||G|$ because you look at $H_{1}H_{2}$ and that is a sub-group (because $G$ abelian) of order q^{2}?
At least, that is one explanation, as I see.

Comment: A simply way to see it is that multiplication by a fixed element defines an injective function (not homomorphism) $G\rightarrow G$. Since the intersection is zero, the products $h_1h_2$, where $h_1\in H_1,h_2\in H_2$ form $q^2$ distinct products.

Answer (score 1):

The only divisors of $pq$ are $1$, $p$, $q$, and $pq$. If $z$ is an element of order $pq$, then $z^p$ is of order $q$ and vice versa. So we may assume that you’ve taken an element $g$ of $G$ that’s of order $p$. It generates a subgroup of order only $p$, so there are other elements. If your next element is of order $pq$, you’re done, and if that next element is of order $q$, you’re also done. So the only remaining possibility is that this second element $h$ is of order $p$ as well, not in $\langle g\rangle$. But then the $p^2$ elements $g^ih^j$ for $0\le i,j<p$ would all be distinct, giving $p^2|pq$, a falsity. So this last possibility doesn’t occur.